# Can't change Mongoose field type unless it != original value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My `myId` field is a String. I want to convert it to Number, so I run this (after updating my Mongoose model field to `Number`):

```
Post.find( { myId : { $exists : true } }).then( function(docs){
  docs.forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.myId = parseInt(doc.myId);
    doc.save();
  })
})
```

However, that doesn't work! `myId` is still a String in MongoDB Compass.

It only works when I change the value:

```
Post.find( { myId : { $exists : true } }).then( function(docs){
  docs.forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.myId = parseInt(doc.myId) + 1000; // => This is the only way I can change the field type to Number! What gives?
    doc.save();
  })
})
```

Why do I have to alter the value in order to change the field type?

## Edit

If I change the value before saving it, it also works:

```
// This works!
doc.myId = parseInt(doc.myId) + 1;
doc.myId = doc.myId - 1;
doc.save();
```

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because Mongoose coerces the data in MongoDB to the type expected by Mongoose.  If you do `console.log(typeof doc.myId)`, what is printed?  It's probably "number".  Since parseInt of number is the same number, Mongoose doesn't detect the change, so it doesn't preserve the type change to the database.

Comment: I believe c1moore is on point, So mongoose would detect any changes to the value for the fields, I guess changes with just the type of the field like no change in the value but just it's type might not be detected.. Ok anyhow let's forget about reads & writes nd this issue what is your MongoDB version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because Mongoose will attempt to coerce the type stored in MongoDB to the type expected by Mongoose.  This means that the Strings have already been converted to a number, so Mongoose doesn't detect any changes when you set `myId` to the value of `parseInt()` since parsing an integer value returns the same integer.

The simplest way to do what you want is to just mark the field as modified, so something like this (untested):

```js
const docs = await Post.find( { myId : { $exists : true } });

await Promise.all(docs.map((doc) => {
  doc.markModified('myId');

  return doc.save();
}));
```

Comment: The OP already stated that the schema was updated ("after updating my Mongoose model field to Number")

Comment: That's also why Mongoose is converting the string from the DB to a number.